# ParseSwift.initialize shows Cannot convert value of type error

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I figure that it is time to start using Swift so I am working on a complete rewrite of an obj C app. This app uses Parse Server and CocoaPods. Following the ParseSwift documentation example in my AppDelegate.swift I added

```
import ParseSwift

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: "AppID", clientKey: "", serverURL: URL(string: "https://server")!, liveQueryServerURL: URL(string: "https://server")!, authentication: ((URLAuthenticationChallenge,(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition,URLCredential?) -> Void) -> Void))
```

and so on ... But the initialize line is showing an error

> Cannot convert value of type '((URLAuthenticationChallenge, (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) -> Void).Type' to expected argument type '((URLAuthenticationChallenge, (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) -> Void)?'

Comment: You can't initialize it like that... `URLAuthenticationChallenge`, `URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition`, and `URLCredential?` is just a type. You need an actual, instantiated object that goes in there

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is an optional field so you don't need to pass a value.

If you are not doing anything with authentication (most cases), you shouldn't pass anything:

```swift
ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: "AppID",
                     clientKey: "",
                     serverURL: URL(string: "https://server")!)
```

When you plan to use authentication for certificate pinning, you should use it as a trailing closure:

```swift
ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: "AppID",
                     clientKey: "",
                     serverURL: URL(string: "https://server")!) { (challenge, credential) in
            credential(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
```